# Mixed formulation of the Poisson equation (FEM)

Tags: finite-element, pde, poisson

I'm solving the Dirichlet problem for the Poisson equation in a 2d domain $D$:
$$
 \begin{cases}
    \Delta u = 0 \quad \text{in $D$}, \\
    u|_{\partial D} = u_0.
 \end{cases}
$$
I'm interested in finding the fluxes of the solution through the boundary and in order to get accurate fluxes (after a discussion in comments to [this post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/27002/1180)) I decided to pass to a mixed formulation (see [this fenics documentation page](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.5.0/python/demo/documented/mixed-poisson/python/documentation.html)):
$$
 \begin{cases}
   \nabla u = \sigma, \\
   \nabla \cdot \sigma = 0, \\
   u|_{\partial D} = u_0.
  \end{cases}
$$
The weak form consists of two equations
$$
   \int_D (\sigma \cdot \tau + \nabla \cdot \tau \; u )dS = \int_{\partial D} \tau \cdot n \; u_0 \, ds \quad \forall \tau \in H^1(div), \\
   \int_D \nabla \cdot \sigma \; v \; dS = 0 \quad \forall v \in L^2.
$$
Next, I consider a triangular finite element basis $\psi_i$ and I put $\sigma = (\sigma^i_x \psi_i, \sigma^j_y \psi_j)$, $\tau = (\tau^i_x \psi_i,\tau^j_y\psi_j)$, $u = u^i \psi_i$, $v = v^j \psi_j$ (where the summation signs are ommited). Putting these expressions in the above equations and taking into account that $\tau$, $v$ are arbitrary, I get the equations
$$
   \int_D \psi_i \psi_j dS \; \sigma_x^j + \int_D \partial_x \psi_i \psi_j dS \; u^j = \int_{\partial D} \psi_i n_x u_0 \, ds, \\
   \int_D \psi_i \psi_j dS \; \sigma_y^j + \int_D \partial_y \psi_i \psi_j dS \; u^j = \int_{\partial D} \psi_i n_y u_0 \, ds, \\
  \int_D \psi_i \partial_x \psi_j dS \; \sigma_x^j + \int_D \psi_i \partial_y \psi_j dS \; \sigma_y^j = 0,
$$ 
where there is a summation over all indices $j$. Now I introduce the matrices
$$
  B_{ij} = \int_D \psi_i \psi_j \, dS, \; B_{x,ij} = \int_D \partial_x \psi_i \psi_j dS, \; B_{y,ij} = \int_D \partial_y \psi_i \psi_j \, dS,
$$
and the vectors
$$
   f_{x,i} = \int_{\partial D} \psi_i n_x u_0 \, ds, \; f_{y,i} = \int_{\partial D} \psi_i n_y u_0 \, ds.
$$
The discrete system can be formulated as
$$
  \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & B_x^T & B_y^T \\
   B_x & B & 0 \\
   B_y & 0 & B 
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} u \\ \sigma_x \\ \sigma_y \end{array}\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ f_x \\ f_y \end{array}\right).
$$
However, if I implement these formulas, I get some rubbish. Could you please point out what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For this problem you cannot use arbitrary finite elements. The finite element spaces should satisfy the so-called discrete inf-sup condition. You did not mention what elements you used so I assume that you used something that does not work like $P_1$ for each variable.

Fortunately there are lots of literature on elements that work. Keywords are "Raviart-Thomas elements" and "Brezzi-Douglas-Marini elements". The monograph by Boffi-Brezzi-Fortin lists various finite element spaces for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @knl’s answer: you may want to check chapter 4 “Mixed Finite Elements” by [Mardal](https://folk.uio.no/kent-and/) (he is one of the developers of Dolfin which you mentioned) et al. of [this](http://www.diffpack.com/?f=book/comp_pde_advanced) book.

They discuss mixed Poisson problem, inf–sup stable FEs, and how it is implemented in Diffpack.